# method null object

Tags: java, android

When I turn off the app and turn it on again, sometimes I get an error like this.

There's an error coming from the 'registerGlobalReceiver' method

```
public void registerGlobalReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter intentFilter) {
    if (!isReceiverRegistered(receiver)) {
                       globalReceivers.add(receiver);
 this line error --->  contextWeakReference.get().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
                       Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Registered global receiver: " + receiver + "  with filter: " + intentFilter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class is just to manage the BroadcastReceivers
so in the activity you need to register the receivers you are about to use, but when you turn off your app you need to unregister your receivers so following best practices you need to use the onCreate or the onStart or the onResume depending of your necessities to register and in the onStop, or onPause or onDestroy depending of your functionality unregister your receivers and your app should stop having that problem.